# Creating a Circular Motion of Sprite in Enchant JS Framework

Tags: javascript, enchantjs

I'm using [Enchant.js framework](http://www.enchantjs.com) to create games. I cannot find a way to create a circular motion for my sprite. Anybody know how ?,

Answer (score 1):

'A Quick Look Into The Math Of Animations With JavaScript' article explains a lot of trigonometry behind circular motion

- http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/quick-look-math-animations-javascript/

@lewster32 example in this JSfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/lewster32/4sj9n927/

```
    var update = function() 
    {
        var period = game.time.now * 0.001;
        var radius = 60;
        square.x = game.world.centerX + Math.cos(period) * radius;
        square.y = game.world.centerY + Math.sin(period) * radius;
    }
```

- http://www.html5gamedevs.com/topic/8529-constant-circular-motion/